# XML - Android Fragment Tab Host error

Tags: java, android, layout, tabs, fragment

When I copy below code. 
I get error..

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

The error is

1. This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.
2. **Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null**

I have searched in Google. I copy every example but still I get error...

Comment: Try using viewpager, if you want to learn more about using viewpager to create sliding tabs, checkout [this](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html) tutorial i made sliding tabs with material design :D